# How to properly get a smoke/fire effect in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, effects

So there is a well known tutorial on Youtube by the BlenderGuru that I watched because I want to try and get into blender and CGI. I know that the tutorial is for modeling a donut, but an issue Im having is that I am unable to render a smoke and fire effect. Following his tutorial and taking the exact same steps to using the Quick Smoke function. I repeated the steps multiply times to see if maybe I missed something, but still nothing. I then went and looked on the Blender Manual to see if maybe I am not using the right effect. So i then tried doing it manually in the Physics Properties tab and yet the only effect i am able to create is balls that flow and fall. Am I missing textures or assets that i have to download separately to have other effects to work?

Comment: Does the domain object have a volume material?

Comment: Did you bake the simulation (under domain properties)?